# Error while running Hive command with DATE as of the colume name

Tags: hive

```
create table Book_inf2(OID int, date timestamp, CUSTOMER_ID string, AMOUNT 
int) row format delimited fields terminated by ',';
```

Error which I got:

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:32 missing Identifier at 'date' near
>   'date' in  create table statement line 1:37 mismatched input
>   'timestamp' expecting ) near 'date' in create  table statement

Note: I am new to the Hive, please help me to get understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Date** is a reserved keyword in hive that's the reason why you are facing issue

However hive allows to use **reserved keywords** as field names, but that's not the best practice to use them.

***To fix the issue:***

Surround **date field name** with **backtick's**

> `

Try with below create table statement

```
hive> create table Book_inf2(OID int, `date` timestamp, CUSTOMER_ID string, AMOUNT int) row format delimited fields terminated by ',';
```